# instagram embeds.js handler to know when the iframe is loaded

Tags: javascript, iframe, twitter, instagram

I'm using embeds.js to display instagram posts on a website.
referring to https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/

I use also the widgets.js for twitter and with it I can load a twit, set an handler to get when the iframe is ready and then call twttr.widgets.load() in this way:

```
twttr.events.bind('rendered', function (event) {
    //do something when the iframe is ready
});
twttr.widgets.load();
```

Does anybody know if there is a similar feature or maybe a workaround to get when the instagram iframe is ready?

After loading the instagram post I use:

```
instgrm.Embeds.process();
```

to render the iFrame.

side note: the application is made with angular/jquery, so the workaround can be done with those libraries.

Thanks in advance,
Daniele

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `iframe` Instagram embed and use the `onload` event handler to trigger a function:

```
<script>
function doSomething(){
   alert("Instagram embed loaded");
}
</script>

<iframe onload="doSomething()" src="https://www.instagram.com/p/8_kRtJBsBq/embed" width="400" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

You can generate an iframe Instagram embed coding using gramfeed:
http://gramfeed.com/instagram/embed

add `onload="someFunction()"` to the generated iframe embed code.

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution if you can not use iframe embeds.

```
window.__igEmbedLoaded = function( loadedItem ) {
  // do something here...
};
```